# Why is ln(x) bigger than log(x)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms

I couldn't find any results. I would like to know why $\ln x$ stays higher than $\log x$. Does it have to do with ase $10$ of $\log$? base $e$ with $\ln x$?

Comment: It doesn't start higher, actually.  When $x$ is between 0 and 1, then $\ln x$ is actually lower than $\log x$.

Comment: Well a smaller number requires a larger exponent to equal the same thing (obviously that's assuming the number is greater than $1$ and thus the exponent is positive).  As @ErickWong stated, if the number desired is _less than_ $1$, then the exponent must be negative and the smaller number requires a "larger" negative exponent to equal the same thing (i.e. it's more negative and thus the exponent is technically less than the smaller absolute value, but less positive).

Answer (score 7):

We have the change of base formula

$$\log_b(x)=\frac{\log_a(x)}{\log_a(b)}$$

This gives rise to the equation $\log_{10}(e)\log_e(x)=\log_{10}(x)$ and we note that $\log_{10}(e)<1$. I assume you mean measuring from $x=1$ onwards, because they meet and cross at that $(1,0)$

Comment: Yes, I was just curious what makes ln x higher than log x.

Comment: I mean, at its most basic level, because $\ln(x)>\log(x)$

Answer (score 3):

The idea of the function $y=log_{10}(x)$ is to find $y$ so that $10^y=x$.

If you take an example $log_{10}100$ compared to $log_2 100$

$log_{10}100=2$, you have to square $10$ to get $100$

$log_{2}100=6.6$, you have to multiply $2$ by itself more than $6$ times to get $100$. It should be clear that since $2$ is smaller than $10$ you have to multiply it by itself more times to get $100$. In the same way $e$ is smaller than $10$ so you'll have to multiply it by itself more times to get any number (any bigger than $1$).

Answer (score 1):

Take two different bases: $2$ and $4$.  Now let's look at what exponent is required to equal some numbers (this is what the logarithm computes):

\begin{align}
2^? = 16 \rightarrow 2^4 = 16 && 4^? = 16 \rightarrow 4^2 = 16\\
2^? = 64 \rightarrow 2^6 = 64 && 4^? = 64 \rightarrow 4^3 = 64 \\
2^? = 1024 \rightarrow 2^{10} = 1024 && 4^? = 1024 \rightarrow 4^5 = 1024
\end{align}

Clearly the smaller base requires a larger exponent to make the same value.  Thus since $e < 10$, if $e^a = 10^b$ then $a > b$ and thus $\ln(x) > \log_{10}(x)$ (for *some* values of $x$).

Let's look at some different numbers with the same two bases above:

\begin{align}
2^? = \frac{1}{16} \rightarrow 2^{-4} = \frac{1}{16} && 4^? = \frac{1}{16} \rightarrow 4^{-2} = \frac{1}{16}\\
2^? = \frac{1}{64} \rightarrow 2^{-6} = \frac{1}{64} && 4^? = \frac{1}{64} \rightarrow 4^{-3} = \frac{1}{64} \\
2^? = \frac{1}{1024} \rightarrow 2^{-10} = \frac{1}{1024} && 4^? = \frac{1}{1024} \rightarrow 4^{-5} = \frac{1}{1024}
\end{align}

In this case, first, notice the *absolute value* of the exponent is *still* greater, but since they are negative, the smaller number requires a "smaller" exponent (a "more negative" exponent).

So when the exponent is negative, meaning $\log_a(x) < 0$ and thus $x < 1$, the smaller base requires a "smaller" exponent (really a more negative exponent).  The general rule of :

$$
\left|\log_a(x)\right| \geq \left|\log_b(x)\right|, a > 1, b > 1, a \leq b
$$

If $a$ and/or $b$ is between $0$ and $1$ then it gets tricky since:

$$
0 < a < 1 \rightarrow \begin{cases}
\log_a(x) < 0 & x > 1 \\
\log_a(x) > 0 & x < 1
\end{cases}
$$

To figure out how the absolute values would compare requires looking at the inverse of the bases.  Let's continue to assume that $\frac{1}{a} < b$ and $a, b > 0$:

1. If $a < b$ then the same rules would apply:
  $$
  \left|\log_{\frac{1}{a}}(x)\right| \geq \left|\log_b(x)\right|
  $$
2. If $a > b$ then the *opposite* rules would apply:
  $$
  \left|\log_{\frac{1}{a}}(x)\right| \leq \left|\log_b(x)\right|
  $$

If *both* $a$ *and* $b$ are between $0$ and $1$ then, since the smaller number would mean the larger inverse (i.e. $\frac{1}{a} < \frac{1}{b} \rightarrow b < a$), the smaller number would make the smaller logarithm.

Here is a summarization, assuming $a, b > 1$ and $a < b$:

\begin{align}
\left|\log_a(x)\right| \geq& \left|\log_b(x)\right| \\
\left|\log_{\frac{1}{a}}(x)\right| \geq& \left|\log_b(x)\right| \\
\left|\log_a(x)\right| \geq& \left|\log_{\frac{1}{b}}(x)\right| \\
\left|\log_{\frac{1}{a}}(x)\right| \geq& \left|\log_{\frac{1}{b}}(x)\right|
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach: $$\log_{10}(x) = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t \cdot(\ln10)} dt < \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} dt = \ln(x)$$

for $x>1$.  This is clear since the area under the graph of  $\frac{1}{t \cdot(\ln10)}$ is strictly contained within the area of the graph of $\frac{1}{t}$ for $t>1$.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:
$$(\frac{d}{dx}10^x>\frac{d}{dx}e^x)$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$$
$$(\frac{1}{\frac{d}{dx}10^x}<\frac{1}{\frac{d}{dx}e^x})$$

---

Let me offer a quick and intuitive approach.

As we know from this famous reciprocal relationship: 
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$$

Which we shall use to help with interpreting the exponential function's natural reciprocal relationships:
$$y=f(x)=e^x$$
$$x=g(y)=log_ey$$
Hence:
$$y=f(x)=(\frac{10}{e}e)^x=(\frac{10}{e})^x(e)^x$$
$$x=g(y)=log_{10}y$$

And in where:
$$\frac{d}{dx}a^xe^x=(\frac{d}{dx}a^x)(e^x)$$

Conclusion:

-$e^x$ and its 1st order derivative is equal to $e^x$.

-Any function proportional to $e^x$ of the form $a^xe^x$ will have a 1st order derivative that is proportional to $e^x$, being $(\frac{d}{dx}a^x)(e^x)$.

-For the case of $(\frac{10}{e}e)^x$, its 1st order derivative is proportional to $e^x$ by a factor ($\frac{d}{dx}a^x$) that is monotically increasing as $\frac{10}{e}=a>1$ for as $10>e$ - $(\frac{d}{dx}10^x>\frac{d}{dx}e^x)$.

-Therefore, taking advantage of $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$, we have $(\frac{1}{\frac{d}{dx}10^x}<\frac{1}{\frac{d}{dx}e^x})$.

---

Supplement: 
For $x<1$, $log_{10}x>log_ex$